Can't connect to encrypted SQL Server connection using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
I have a .NET Core website where I've replaced the deprecated System.Data.SqlClient library with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, and can no longer connect to the default SQL Server instance on my server.
I was originally using Server=localhost in the connection string, but since changing library this brings up the error message

The certificate received from the remote server does not contain the
expected name. It is therefore not possible to determine whether we
are connecting to the correct server. The server name we were
expecting is localhost. The TLS connection request has failed.

I have a wildcard certificate for *.mydomain.example in place under SQL Server Configuration and 'Force Encryption' turned on, which was working fine, and still does for other sites using System.Data.SqlClient. Despite using localhost I assume that the encryption was working as when the certificate periodically expired, the SQL connection would fail.
I've added an A record to my DNS server for server.mydomain.example which points to 127.0.0.1, changed the connection string to Server=server.mydomain.example and I no longer get the original error. Instead I get

Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
Server

I've also tried adding an entry to the hosts file but get the same issue.
If I force TCP (as Named Pipes is disabled anyway) with Server=TCP:server.mydomain.example then I get

TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network
connection

Rolling back to the old library is the obvious fix, but I'd like to understand why it's not working.


"I've added an A record to my DNS server"  That makes your entire network resolve that way. You might want to add a hosts file entry on the specific machine instead, or set the DNS entry to use the server's actual (static/reserved) IP. Otherwise, requiring the names to match is expected (I would never expect a connection to "localhost" to accept a wildcard cert for *.mydomain.example). If that's your old connection string, it's likely the old code is not actually doing any encryption.


Rolling back to the old library is the obvious fix no it's not. The real error is the one in the message - you're trying to connect with a name, localhost, that doesn't match the certificate. You should connect with a valid domain name, ie mycomputer.mydomain.example. DON'T try to hack DNS. Your machine already has an IP that's not 127.0.0.1, which is assigned a name in the domain that's NOT localhost. It's your computer's name followed by the domain.

The whole point of HTTPS and SSL isn't encryption - a malicious proxy eg in a cafe, or a WiFi pineapple could intercept the initial connection attempt and pretend it's the server. The point is ensuring no middleman is snooping on the connection by signing and verifying packets through a certificate that itself gets verified to ensure it's for the server you're connecting to. That's why the server name and certificate name must match.

@PanagiotisKanavos I can see why the names need to match; I'm just unsure why it previously worked without complaint when they didn't. Now I need to establish why an FQDN which should match the certificate still can't connect.

The old drivers/libs maybe didn't verify certificates by default, ie. TrustServerCertificate=true was default, but later versions really likes to focus on security

You don't need to establish an FQDN. You're trying to connect to your own machine. If the machine isn't in the domain specified by the certificate, don't use that certificate. In fact, if you're connecting locally the most secure option is to enable and Shared Memory. To connect to localhost you can create a certificate for localhost

If you're using v5.0 or better of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient then maybe it's worth looking into the HostNameInCertificate connection string property while continuing to use Server=localhost;....

To connect to the local machine, you shouldn't use locahost or mycomputer.mydomain.example, just use . for example Data Source=.

The HostNameInCertificate property has worked. Thanks @AlwaysLearning and others for their help.
